# LinkedIn PHP api issues

Tags: php, api, rest, linkedin-api

Today, after we migrated to the new members permissions api, everything goes wrong.
Im using the cosumer key and secret that i've got from the linkedin api dashboard itself with the oauth token and secret as well.

There is 3 kind of problems that keeps on coming:
first one:

```
{"errorCode": 0,"message": "Could not find person based on: ~","requestId": "7GPT96SW3C","status": 404,"timestamp": 1369827647671}
```

second:

```
<error><status>401</status><timestamp>1369826490661</timestamp><request-id>ZYWPUD43G3</request-id><error-code>0</error-code><message>[unauthorized]. The token used in the OAuth request is not valid. ******</message></error>
```

third:

```
com.linkedin.anet.auth.pub.ANetAuthException: other: anetID=*****
```

has anyone got some of these too? if yes, so how did you solved them?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have authenticated the user, you no longer need to make the access token calls - simply store the access token and reuse that for the subsequent requests.

Comment: Thats not the problem, the problem is that i cant use the access token after i got it.

Answer (score 0):

Check are you sending a request once or twice for authentication, there may be the case your token getting replaced by another request.

Comment: This sounds more like a comment than an answer

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten the "401<" and fixed it by correcting the URL which I was formatting incorrectly and consequently requesting a resource that did not exists (reported as unauthorized). You probably have the same issue with your 404 error. Can you please post the specific URLs you are using. That would give a little more insight. Also, make sure that you are not passing params via GET when you should be passing them via POST and that all your POST requests are via HTTPS